# ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded while converting html to json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I am getting the error while executing the following python script.
The issue is with converting html output to json . It will be very helpful if you help me to solve the problem.

```
import urllib2
import json`

url ='http://localhost:40102/cq/etc/replication/agents.author/publish- 
u11cmspu1.html'
username='admin'
password='admin'
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, username, password)``
authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passman)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
urllib2.install_opener(opener)
pagehandle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
json_response=json.loads(pagehandle.read())
# output=json.load(pagehandle.read())
print json_response



ERROR :

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./repQstatus.py", line 18, in <module>
json_response=json.loads(pagehandle.read())
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: What is pagehandle.read() value?

Comment: Its basically a html output.

Comment: It should be JSON. Please post `print(type(pagehandle.read())` and value of `pagehandle.read()`

Answer (score 0):

What is going on here is the return value of `pagehandle.read()` is returning an string that is not identifiable as JSON by the python json library.

There could definitely still be JSON inside the response of `pagehandle.read()`, but something is keeping it from being properly evaluated.